# I get Key Error: "po5" after everything is done

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

```
car={"po1":50,"po2":"-","po3":15,"po4":"+","po5":12}
vocar = list(car.keys())
inter=0
def cal(car,vocar,inter):
    while len(car)!=1:
        for inter in range(len(car)):
            if car.get(vocar[inter],0)=="+":
                new=car.get(vocar[inter-1])+car.get(vocar[inter+1])
                car.pop(vocar[inter])
                car.pop(vocar[inter+1])
                car.update({vocar[inter-1]:new})
                car1=car
                vocar1=list(car1.keys())
                inter1=0
                cal(car1,vocar1,inter1)
            elif car.get(vocar[inter],0)=="-":
                new=car.get(vocar[inter-1])-car.get(vocar[inter+1])
                car.pop(vocar[inter])
                car.pop(vocar[inter+1])
                car.update({vocar[inter-1]:new})
                car1=car
                vocar1=list(car1.keys())
                inter1=0
                cal(car1,vocar1,inter1)
    print(car)            
cal(car,vocar,inter)
```

I keep getting a key error even if I get what I wanted, which is `{'po1': 47}`.

But after everything is done, it gives me a key error. Please help!

Comment: `vocar[inter+1]` is out of range :)

Comment: thank you very much for your response but i dont understand how it can be out of range

Comment: short answer: dictionaries are unordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- At first:

```
while len(car)!=1
```

You pop item from car and try to make a `recursion function` then you can use:

```py
    if not car:
        return
    for inter in range(len(car)):
        # ....
```

- When you make a `loop` like this:

```py
for inter in range(len(car))
```

that means:

```
| loop | inter |
|:----:|:-----:|
|   1  |   0   | car => [X, X, X ,X ,X]
|   2  |   1   | car => [X, X, X ,X]
|   3  |   2   | car => [X, X, X]  ! ERR !
|   4  |   3   | 
|   5  |   4   |
```

in `loop 3` you have an error (maybe ;))

you can use the main `dict`:

```py
for inter in car:
```

- According above, You didn't need `vocar` anymore:

```
if car.get(inter,0)=="+":
```

- "po1" is `str` and "po2" is `int` then you can't use `+` operator between `int` and `int`.
- ### dictionaries are unordered

  That means, every time you run it, item arrangments may be changed! so I change it:

```py
car = [("po1",50), ("po2","-"),("po3",15),("po4","+"),("po5",12)]
```

- We changed `car` then we can do this:

```
        if inter[1] == "+":
            car[head-1] = (inter[0], car[head-1][1]+car[head+1][1])
```

- finally, we MUST remove `car[head+1]` at first and then remove `car[inter]`.

```py
car = [("po1",50), ("po2","-"),("po3",15),("po4","+"),("po5",12)]

def cal(car):
    head = 0
    if not car:
        return
    for inter in car:
        if inter[1] == "+":
            car[head-1] = (inter[0], car[head-1][1]+car[head+1][1])
            car.remove(car[head+1])
            car.remove(inter)
            cal(car)
        elif inter[1] =="-":
            car[head-1] = (inter[0], car[head-1][1]-car[head+1][1])
            car.remove(car[head+1])
            car.remove(inter)
            cal(car)
        head += 1
    return car[0][1]

print(cal(car))

OUT:
===
47
```